# Obtener valor de campo en variable c# con linq

Tags: linq

como puedo obtener el valor de un campo especifico de mi vista con linq en este caso quiero obtener el campo "Folio", uso la siguiente query

```
var idFolio= entidad.View_FACTURA
                            .Where(x=> x.SERIE == "P")
                             .OrderByDescending(x => x.id_FACTURA)
                              .Take(1);
```

Comment: por qué no utilizas el `select` para obtener ese campo Folio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se obtiene valor a través de una query select

```
(from ex in entidad.View_FACTURA where ex.SERIE == "P" select ex).OrderByDescending(x => x.id_FACTURA).First().FOLIO;
```